# Packet injection with scapy and monitor mode

Tags: scapy

Do I need to put my wifi card into monitor mode to be able to inject packets with scapy? Or monitor mode is just for sniffing in scapy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in monitor mode ,with scapy, depending on your chipset you can monitor and inject packets. I use Ralink chipset and am able to monitor as well as inject packets